Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
I copy pasted a gfg code (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-mongodb-with-reactjs/) which connects mongodb with react.I followed the steps as mentioned but got the error "Uncaught runtime errors: ERROR JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" All the  json formats are correct and same as available in the code. My friends did the same thing but didn't encounter this error.It worked once out of the blue , I was able to send data to my mongodb compass but when I undid the changes and then copy pasted the working code it didn't work.Please Please help me rectify.
// Frontend code 
// Filename - App.js

import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let result = await fetch(
            'http://localhost:3001/register', {
                method: "post",
                body: JSON.stringify({ name, email }),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        );
        result = await result.json();
        console.warn(result);
        if (result) {
            alert("Data saved successfully");
            setEmail("");
            setName("");
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h1>This is React WebApp</h1>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                <button type="submit" onClick={handleOnSubmit}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;


// Code for mongoose config in backend
// Filename - backend/index.js

// To connect with your mongoDB database
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {
    dbName: 'yourDB-name',
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, err => err ? console.log(err) : console.log('Connected to yourDB-name database'));

// Schema for users of app
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    },
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
User.createIndexes();

// For backend and express
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

console.log("App listen at port 3001");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, resp) => {
    resp.send("App is Working");
    // You can check backend is working or not by 
    // entering http://loacalhost:3001
    // If you see App is working means
    // backend working properly
});

app.post("/register", async (req, resp) => {
    try {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        let result = await user.save();
        result = result.toObject();
        if (result) {
            delete result.password;
            resp.send(req.body);
            console.log(result);
        } else {
            console.log("User already register");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        resp.send("Something Went Wrong");
    }
});

app.listen(3001);


Note:We didn't even use JSON.parse()

Show the actual error, don't paraphrase it. Just copy-paste the whole thing, and I bet it says the unexpected character was <, meaning you forgot to verify that what you got back was actual JSON instead of a 403/404/etc error web page.

When you debug, which specific operation produces the error?  For example, if it was result = await result.json(); then your next debugging step would be to observe what actual response content the server returned, because it wouldn't be JSON.

@mike-pomax-kamermans  The title of this post itself is the copy pasted error.

@David Yes the line  result = await result.json();  is the  error producer

Your title is not where details go. Your title is the summary of the problem, and the actual full error goes in your post. So to rephrase: add code that checks what you actually got from your fetch call before calling .json(), because right now your code simply assumes it's JSON, even though you have zero guarantee that it will be.

@Vasita: You can use your browser's debugging tools to observe the network requests/responses, in which you can observe the (non-JSON) response from the server.

@David @ Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans
I'm a beginner at this , so what do I do to ensure that the received input is in JSON format

@Vasita: You'd correct whatever problem is causing the server to return something other than JSON.  For example, if the server is responding with an error then you would need to find out what that error is and address it.  Or if the server is responding with a web page instead of the expected JSON then the server may be failing to correctly route requests to the appropriate handlers.  There are a variety of potential problems causing this result, and you'd need to continue to investigate.  We can help with that as you narrow down the problem to something more specific.

@David How do I check that in debugging tools

@Vasita: In Chrome's debugging tools it's on the Network tab.  Other browsers may have something similar.

@David it says Cannot POST /register in the response tab under networks tab.The get is working but the post isn't . In the request it says JSON and under it it displayed the info I gave

@Vasita: Is there any indication as to why it can't send that POST request?  When you debug the server-side code, is any request received for that POST endpoint?  Is the server-side code logging anything to the server's console?  (You can of course add more console.log statements to that endpoint to log more information.)

@David Ya in the post , requests tab , there is the Json object with the data I entered. And there is no reason stating as to why it cant send the post

@Vasita: Is the request failing instantly, or after hanging for some period of time?  Is there anything in the response body from the server?  Is the server-side code logging anything to the server's console? (You can of course add more console.log statements to that endpoint to log more information.)

@David after I hit the submit button in my form,instantly its showing the error

@Vasita: And nothing on the browser's development console provides more information about the problem?  It's sounding like you're likely missing some piece of information being reported in the debugging tools somewhere, and you'll need to continue to investigate what that information is.  Some specific error prevents this request from taking place.  It could be something as subtle as the HTTP response code from the server.  (e.g. 404)  Without knowing what that error is, all anybody can do is guess.

@David it says 404 status for the post

@Vasita: Then the endpoint wasn't found, which implies that the server-side code shown isn't what's being requested.  Perhaps you're running some other server on the same port and not the code you think you're running?  Perhaps you're showing unsaved changes to the server's JavaScript code and the actual running server isn't using this code?  Perhaps something else?  But the error has nothing to do with JSON.  The error is telling you that the URL being requested was not found on that server.

@David Thankyou I will look into it and get back if required
